# How to transfer a commit from master to another branch?

Tags: git

I worked on master and forgot that I did not change the branch, tried to push, but because of the limitations I could not (I am happy), I changed to develop, but the commit remained on master, how can I transfer it to develop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give the full version of the cherry-pick solution to this situation (which also deletes the commit from master afterwards)

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick master
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Answer (score 1):

By using [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git).

By using reset you can take the changes back into your working tree.

Then you switch to the branch you want to commit to, and then commit the changes.

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git checkout develop
git commit
```

Where `HEAD~1` refers to two commits ago. You can also use the commit-ish of the commit *prior* to the erroneous commit.

`--soft` means take the changes out of the commit (but leave them in to your workspace) and also keep them in the 'staging' area.

Without `--soft` git defaults to `--mixed` which would reset the staging area as well, which isn't a big deal if you have no other local changes. You would just have to re-add them via `git add xyz.txt` or whatever.

Comment: it just takes my commit back

Comment: @Nick I liked your solution, but did you not forget to re-add files to the index before the commit? Since mixed reset clears the index, changes are not staged after it. Unless I'm missing something? Or even better, you could do a `reset --soft` instead of a reset `--mixed` and then not bother with re-adding?

Answer (score 0):

I understood how to do this, I need to go to the branch to which I want to transfer my changes and use the `git cherry-pick commit identifier`

Comment: This does *not* delete the commit from master. If you don't have the faulty commit on `master` any more, I guess you tried Nick's solution beforehand and *that* got rid of it on `master`. And since the commit still existed (though not on `master` dangling), the cherry-pick worked and got it on your `develop` branch.

Comment: For convenience, you can feed a branch ref to `cherry-pick` and it will use its tip (last) commit, it's sometimes slightly easier than first searching for your `commit identifier` (SHA-1)